# Use of getFlashAttributes() in Spring's RedirectAttributes

Tags: java, spring

In order to access the redirect attributes in the redirected method, we utilize the model's map, like this :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView handleGet(Model map) {
     String some = (String) map.asMap().get("some");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView handlePost(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttributes("some", "thing");
    return new ModelAndView().setViewName("redirect:/foo/bar");
  }

}
```

But, why can't we access them in this way :

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView handleGet(RedirectAttributes redAttr) {
         String some = redAttr.getFlashAttributes().get("some");
      }
```

If the only purpose of adding flashAttributes is that they become available to the model in the redirected method, what's the purpose of `getFlashAttributes()` ?

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectAttributes` are for **setting** flash attributes before redirection. They are merged into `model` after the redirection so there is no reason to access them again via `RedirectAttributes` again as you have suggested.

---

Being able to work with the attributes just like with a map might be useful. You can check what have you set (`containsKey`, `isEmpty`, ...). However the use of the wildcard generic parameter `Map<String, ?> getFlashAttributes()` prevents writing into map and it is strange why they have used it instead of a plain `Object` parameter.

Comment: use "redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute"