# Unable to populate modelAttribute in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, modelattribute

I am unable to get the ModelAttribute for second request.
My first request is initForm() method I prepared Command object and able to display the command in jsp.

Through initForm() I am populating command and that command I want in editForm when I will do ajax call.

Here is my spring form

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addstudentdetails.htm" commandName="command">
 Ignore what is inside this 

 Name: Shoaib Age:23  <a href="#" onclick="editstudentdetails(1,0)">edit</a>

</form:form>
```

My ajax request:

```
function editStudentDetails(studentId,index){
       $.ajax(
        {url:"editstudentdetails.htm",
         method:"GET",
         data:{"action":"edit","id":studentId,"index":index},
            success: function(data) {
                   jQuery("#studentDetailsDiv").html(data)
            }

        }

      )
   }
```

In `editStudentDetails()` method I have method ajax call to go `editForm()` of the controller.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller

public class StudentDetailsController {

@Autowired
private StudentDetailsDAO studentDetailsDAO;

@RequestMapping(value="/studentdetails.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap map){
    String action=request.getParameter("action");
    StudentDetailsCommand command=new StudentDetailsCommand();
    System.out.println("in controller"+action);
    command.setStudents(studentDetailsDAO.findAll());
    map.addAttribute("command", command);

    return "studentdetails";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/editstudentdetails.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(ModelMap map,HttpServletRequest request){
  map.addObject("index", request.getParameter("index"));
    StudentDetailsCommand command=(StudentDetailsCommand)map.get("command");
  System.out.println(command);
  System.out.println(command.getStudents());//NullPointerException here.
  map.addObject("command", command);
    return "studentdetails";
 }
}
```

Even tried @ModelAttribute("studentDetailsCommand") but didn't worked.

I am new to Spring 3.0 and I followed all solutions which are given here but nothing worked.Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: What is the second request? What model attribute are you talking about?

Comment: second  request made by ajax call which comes in editForm method and i getting it through map.get("xxx")

Comment: When i click on edit link it is ajax request which i send.Let me add that ajax method too.

Comment: Updated my question.Am I clear to u??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model attributes only exist during the life cycle of one `HttpServletRequest`. Consider reading [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999874/spring-where-the-model-addattributeskey-values-are-stored).

In your `initForm` method, you do the following

```
map.addAttribute("command", command);
```

this add an attribute named `command` to the model attributes. This attribute will eventually find its way into the `HttpServletRequest` attributes and be available to your JSP. In here

```
<form:form [...] modelAttribute="studentDetailsCommand" commandName="command">
```

first of all, `modelAttribute` and `commandName` have the same purpose, ie. to find an attribute in the model. If you remove `commandName` you will get an Exception because there is no model attribute named `studentDetailsCommand`. Here your `commandName`'s value is overwriting your `modelAttribute`'s value.

When the Servlet container is finished rendering your JSP, the rendered content is sent as the body of the HTTP response. At this point, the request has been handled and the `HttpServletRequest` and the model attributes are garbage collected.

When you send your new request through AJAX, there is no longer any model attribute named `studentDetailsCommand` (there actually never was).

Consider using [Flash Attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes).

Related:

- [How to read flash attributes after redirection in Spring MVC 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763779/how-to-read-flash-attributes-after-redirection-in-spring-mvc-3-1)
- [Spring RedirectAttributes: addAttribute vs addFlashAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470111/spring-redirectattributes-addattribute-vs-addflashattribute)
- [Use of getFlashAttributes() in Spring's RedirectAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878389/use-of-getflashattributes-in-springs-redirectattributes)

Comment: So can u tell me how i can solve my problem.Should i remove my modelAttribute from form or change it to "command".Please check my updated question which i followed your suggestion.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Yes, use either `modelAttribute` or `commandName`, not both. As I stated in my answer, look into flash attributes.

Comment: What happening here is initForm is populating attributes and when another request gets starts then command is not their in the modelMap....so shud i add command as flashAttribute in initForm()

Comment: @ShoaibChikate That will make it available in the next request. If that is what you want to do, then yes.

Comment: Added redirectAttribute in initForm but i m unable to access in jsp.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Unable to access what?

Comment: reDirect.addFlashAttribute("command",command) this i added in initForm   but in studentDetails.jsp when i print ${command} gives nothing.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Please edit your question with what you are currently trying.

Comment: I solved by storing modelAttribute as in SessionAttribute so it is available for me for my next request. You can update your answer so i can accept it according

Comment: @ShoaibChikate That's what `RedirectAttributes` and `FlashMap` does already. The `RedirectAttributes` stores your flash attributes in a `ModelMap` which is merged with the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. That `ModelMap` is also used to generate a `FlashMap` which is stored in the `HttpSession` and retrieved in the next request.

Comment: Ok bro thanks for your time and help.Learnt new concept about ReDirectAttributes.

Comment: Hope this question and answer helps many user with same requirement.